# How to read/write 64-bit unsigned little-endian integers?

Tags: php

[`pack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) doesn't support them, so how to read and write 64-bit unsigned little-endian encoded integers?

Comment: This didn’t help? http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#109328

Comment: 64-bit unsigned integers are not available in any PHP build AFAIK. So you 'd need something like GMP.

Comment: @Jon 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF comes out as float(1.844674407371E+19) instead of 18446744073709551615.

Comment: @Mark: Sure it would come out as a float, but I'm not sure how that is related to my comment.

Comment: Why not just split/combine to two 32-bit unsigned integers and read/write them in little-endian format with two calls?

Comment: @Jon Oh....I read your comment wrong. I thought you said they *are* available. In that case, yes, you're right ;)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Would I just multiply/divide the high chunk by 2^32 then? (considering bcmath nor GMP seem to have shift)?

Comment: You need either shift or divide and you need some way to mask out the lower 32-bits, which might happen just by converting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a [helper class](https://bitbucket.org/mnbayazit/ptilz/src/3976ec1d58e4/src/Bin.php#cl-97) for packing/unpacking 64-bit unsigned ints.

The relevant bit is just two lines:

```
$ints = unpack("@$offset/Vlo/Vhi", $data);
$sum = Math::add($ints['lo'], Math::mul($ints['hi'], '4294967296'));
```

(`Math::*` is a simple wrapper around bcmath)

And packing:

```
$out .= pack('VV', (int)bcmod($args[$idx],'4294967296'), (int)bcdiv($args[$idx],'4294967296'));
```

It splits the 64-bit ints into two 32-bit ints, which 64-bit PHP should support :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider 64 bit numbers as an opaque chunk of 8 bytes of binary data and use the usual string manipulation functions to handle them (i.e. `substr` and the dot operator above all).

Whenever (and if) you need to perform arithmetics on them, you can use a couple of wrapper functions to encode/decode that chunk in its hexadecimal representation (in my implementation I call this intermediate type `hex64`) and use the external library you prefer to do the real work:

```
<?php

/* Save as test.php */

function chunk_to_hex64($chunk) {
    assert(strlen($chunk) == 8);
    return strrev(bin2hex($chunk));
}

function hex64_to_chunk($hex64) {
    assert(strlen($hex64) == 16);
    return strrev(pack('h*', $hex64));
}


// Test code:

function to_hex64($number) {
    $hex64 = base_convert($number, 10, 16);
    // Ensure the hex64 is left padded with '0'
    return str_pad($hex64, 16, '0');
}

for ($number = 0.0; $number < 18446744073709551615.0; $number += 2932031007403.0) {
    $hex64 = to_hex64($number);
    $hex64_reencoded = chunk_to_hex64(hex64_to_chunk($hex64));
    assert($hex64_reencoded == $hex64, "Result is $hex64_reencoded, expected $hex64");
}

$data = file_get_contents('test.php');
// Skip the last element because it is not 8 bytes
$chunks = array_slice(str_split($data, 8), 0, -1);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $hex64 = to_hex64($number);
    $chunk_reencoded = hex64_to_chunk(chunk_to_hex64($chunk));
    assert($chunk_reencoded == $chunk, "Result is $chunk_reencoded, expected $chunk");
}
```

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is > PHP_INT_MAX, even on 64-bit machines. Was that intentional?

Comment: This is part of the testing, so it does not matter: I don't have a 32 platform at hand. Anyway I changed it to use floats, so I think it could run on 32 bit platforms without problems.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF already gets auto-cast to a float. The loop doesn't even use `$number` actually, so I'm not sure what you're testing.

Comment: The loop uses `$number`, but my last edit screwed up the formatting. I just added the missing newline.